# Combinations By Percentage Algorithim

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

```
Bucket A    Bucket B     Bucket C       Bucket D
30% blue    30% green    10% yellow     50% brown
40% navy    60% orange   40% violet     50% black
15% red     10% torquise 10% gray     
15% white                40% magenta   


Sample output combination: blue, orange, gray, black
```

Above I have specific colors that can go in specific buckets. based on the percentages (each bucket must be spread out by 100%) I want to use the colors in the specific buckets. In order to make a comibantion you must use 1 color from each bucket. How can I list the total possible combinations?

Find the unique set of rows based on the percentages used by each column(bucket)

Comment: Are you looking for a method to generate the output or just the final result?

Comment: A method to generate output. All the cominations

Answer (score 1):

The method to generate the desired result is called the "Cartisian Product" of Set1, Set2, Set3 and Set4.

One way to generate the result, quickly, is to create 4 tables in a RDBMS and run the query below without a condition:

SELECT FROM Set1, Set2, Set3, Set4

Another algorithmic approach may be using the links below describe how you may generate the result using a program:

[generating-all-possible-combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations)

[how-can-i-compute-a-cartesian-product-iteratively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419370/how-can-i-compute-a-cartesian-product-iteratively)

[cartesian-product-of-n-sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106784/cartesian-product-of-n-sets)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Would you mind showing an example how to use this in my case? I understand programming examples

Comment: Sure, which approach do you prefer? The SELECT FROM is the easiest. I can set it for you on the web if you like and pass you a link.

Comment: Thats fine. I know a little C# or sql

Comment: I have created a working example that lists the top 100 combinations at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dcd6d/3

Comment: Thank you Kareem. I am not understanding from the example how you are incorporating the calculation of the percentage of each color used in your example

Comment: It seems like in the the example you have percentage as just a field. I need to ensure in the ouput Bucket A for example only uses navy in 40% of the entire output set

Comment: Yes I used a separate field to give you more control. It does not make a difference whether you have 1 or more fields. The result is the same. I also made a small change to show the percentages with each color. Note that the percentages should (if I understand what they mean) add up to 1 but they don't - This is something you need to check further. Example: 30% blue    30% green    10% yellow     50% brown.

Comment: For each bucket the percentage will be 100% total. So the final output, if I were to look at the percentage of green used in bucket B it'd be 30% for example

Comment: In this example: Example: 30% blue, 30% green, 10% yellow, 50% brown, the total is not 100%. This is taken from your question top row across buckets.

Comment: Rows do not have to add up to a 100% only the columns. The final output should show the columns (buckets) in the correct percentage

Comment: OK, so what I have for you should work.

Comment: How do I make the columns the certain percentage? Can you add that to the example?

Comment: Please explain what you mean? The numbers shown can be shown as percentage values so instead of 0.3, it could be formatted to look like 30% is this what you want?

Comment: how do I add the filter to the sql to do the percentages of the items. Where are the percentages being applied to the colors in the example?

Comment: @Kareem Find the unique set of rows based on the percentages used by each column(bucket) is another way for saying it

Comment: Please give an example, also, I recommend that you open a new question in Stackoverflow.com since the question does not belong to this site anymore.